# asp.net fancybox load image bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, fancybox

Below is the output of the fancybox iframe from google chrome
[image]

And Here is the output of the fancybox ifrom from IE
[image]

Here is the Markup page code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*
        *   Examples - images
        */

        $("[id*=img]").fancybox();

        $('.fancyframe').fancybox({
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'type': 'iframe',
            'width': 1024,
            'height': 768
        });
    });
</script>
<a class="fancyframe" href="/imgLoader.aspx"><img src="/imgLoader.aspx"></a>
```

Here is the code behind of imgLoader.aspx

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               byte[] a = Common.GetImage();
   Response.BinaryWrite(a);
        }
```

Why chrome only loads the byte array instead of the image while IE can display the image and how to fix this bug?

Comment: Does the file `imgLoader.aspx` return anything else apart from an image?

Comment: JFK: no, it just return the byte array of that image..

Comment: Problem solved by adding Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; to the response page

Comment: another alternative would be adding `"type":"image"` (instead of `iframe`) to your fancybox script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are just sending down a byte array and aren't telling the browser what it is.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               byte[] a = Common.GetImage();
               Response.BinaryWrite(a);
        }
```

Try adding:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

Before you call Response.BinaryWrite

Edit: FYI, I usually also call `Response.Clear()` before writing out the image, and then `Response.End` after.

So:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               Response.Clear();
               byte[] a = Common.GetImage();
               Response.BinaryWrite(a);
               Response.End();
        }
```

Why? Just to make sure ASP.NET doesn't have any other junk it's sending down to the browser that might confuse it.